# Why doesn't ConcurrentModificationException happen with remove method of LinkedList?

Tags: java

```
Deque<Employee> employeeDeque = new LinkedList<>();
        employeeDeque.offerLast(new Employee("Michael", 250));
        employeeDeque.offerLast(new Employee("John", 250));
            Iterator iterator = employeeDeque.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next();
            employeeDeque.remove(new Employee("Michael", 250));
    }
```

The same code with ArrayList with produce this exception, but remove on LinkedList doesn't. Why is it so? Add() and Offer() methods still produce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Javadoc for `LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) says,

> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed...Fail-fast iterators throw `ConcurrentModificationException` on a best-effort basis.